# cannot import name Client error while using twilio

Tags: python, twilio

I am using the following code:

```
from twilio.rest import Client

account_sid = "xxxxxxxxxxx"

auth_token  = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"

client = Client(account_sid, auth_token)

message = client.messages.create(
    to="xxxxxxxxx", 
    from_="+xxxxxxxx",
    body="Hello from Python!")

print(message.sid)
```

I have also used : pip install twilio
and    conda install -c ceyhun twilio    from terminal (MacOS). But the error pertains as --  ImportError: cannot import name Client

Please help me out.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ImportError: cannot import name TwilioRestClient](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41013556/importerror-cannot-import-name-twiliorestclient)

Comment: thanks but this was not the case with me. Anyways I figured out myself. Firstly I uninstalled the current twilio using pip uninstall twilio. Then installed it back. Everything fine now. Don't know why this happened with my previous installation, but fine now. Thanks for the link too :)

Answer (score 0):

Twilio Evangelist here.

That is a common error when the python version and pip libraries are not common. My recommendation is to create a virtual environment to isolate your python/pip versions from your OS versions. To do it, use the Python venv module as follows:

```
cd your_project
python -m venv /venv # The path of your virtual environment
```

Then, activate your virtual environment:

```
source venv/bin/activate
```

You should be able to see a change in your terminal; that means that your virtual environment is active and you could install the libraries and use it:

```
./venv/bin/pip install twilio
./venv/bin/python your_python_file.py
```

You can get additional information of virtual environments here: https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html