# TwilioRestClient removed

Tags: python, twilio, twilio-api

```
tClient= TwilioRestClient(sid, token)
```

This code throws exception:

> twilio.base.obsolete.ObsoleteException: TwilioRestClient has been
>   removed from this version of the library. Please refer to current
>   documentation for guidance.

Can't seem to find a reference to this anywhere, this worked a few days ago!

Using python 3.7 and VS2017

Comment: Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/41036484/1000551

Answer (score 5):

use

```
from twilio.rest import Client

tClient= Client(sid, token)
```

as TwilioRestClient was deprecated.

Answer (score 4):

TwilioRestClient was depreciated remove the words 'TwilioRestClient' and replace it as below:

```
from twilio.rest import Client

account = "Account number for Twilio"
token = "Token for Twilio Account"

client = Client(account, token)

message = client.messages.create(to="+ReceiverPhone#", from_="+TwilioPhone#",
                             body="Text message you are sending to receiver")
#print response back from Twilio
print message
```

Answer (score 1):

Must be working.

```
from twilio.rest import Client
# Your Account SID from twilio.com/console
account_sid = "asfdasdfasdfasdfsadfasdfsadfa"
# Your Auth Token from twilio.com/console
auth_token  = "asfdsadfasdfasdfasdfasfas"

client = Client(account_sid, auth_token)

message = client.messages.create(
to="+asdfasdfasfd",
from_="+asfdsafdsafsaf",
body="hello mister x")

print(message.sid)
```

Here is the real link

> https://www.twilio.com/docs/libraries/python